# How do head-tracking devices SmartNav, TrackerPro, HeadMouse Extreme, & HeadMaster compare in terms of mouse and cursor vs movement accuracy?

Tags: mice, adaptive-technology

I am looking for a head-controlled mouse controlled with neck movements. I have found

- [SmartNav](https://naturalpoint.com/smartnav/) (400 to 600 USD) [[discontinued](https://forums.naturalpoint.com/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=18453&sid=7eb79dc36c46269f591882c90696015f)],
- [TrackerPro](http://www.spectronics.com.au/product/tracker-pro) (1550 USD),
- [HeadMouse Extreme/Nano](http://www.orin.com/access/headmouse/) (995 USD),
- [HeadMaster](http://www.evas.com/Datasheets/DataSheet088.htm) (?? USD).
- [Abili Mouse](https://abilitare.com/products/abili-mouse) (799 USD)

How do they compare in terms of accuracy when moving the mouse cursor? My setting is multi-monitor (6). I am open to other devices as well (controlled with neck movements).

Comment: How does head tracking work? Controlled by neck movements? By tracking where your eyes are focusing? By some ad hoc controls like twitching your nose to click?

Comment: @Gilles neck movements. Gaze tracking systems aren't good or super expensive (> 1kUSD) and don't support well multi-monitor. BCI even worse. To click: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3457/903 More info: http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.5907

Answer (score 5):

I would start with only systems that are "self contained", meaning they need no software or special drivers installed.  These units will be recognized as a standard mouse and the OS will use a standard HID driver.

There are 2 main technologies used in developing head controlled mice.  Accelerometer/Gyro based systems like [eeZee Mouse](http://www.lazeetek.com/html/eezee_mouse.html) Tracer and Headmaster are generally the FASTEST and MOST ACCURATE.  The camera based systems which track head or eye movement seem to be the most widely marketed, although often more expensive and somewhat less responsive; including: Accupoint, Camera Mouse, myGaze, ViVo Mouse, Eagle Eyes, Erica, Eye Gaze, Eye Guide, Eye Mouse, Quick Glance, PCEye, Vision Key.

Most reputable manufacturers have a demo or loaner program in order to "test drive" their products for little or no cost.  Each state has a [lending library](http://www.resnaprojects.org/nattap/activities/deviceloans.html) of Assistive Technology devices.

An old medical evaluation of head-controlled mice can be found under the title of "[Efficacy of three head-pointing devices for a mouse emulation task](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14651252)".  My newbie status prevents me from including more than 2 links.

Comment: Thanks. Yes eye/gaze tracking systems are currently not so good. I find SmartNav to be fast (= no lag) and accurate, and is cheaper than eeZee Mouse Tracer. But I don't have enough experience with other systems to compare against. Emotiv headset contains a gyro and seemed pretty good when I tried it a few years ago.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all four devices you asked to compare. In terms of accuracy -and responsiveness- *Headmaster and Headmouse Extreme are the best*. Nothing beat them, they are just perfect like a standard mouse is. If you have a good head movement you'll take the best from them.

I'm a quadriplegia C4-C5 and I design with an **Headmouse Extreme** with sip/puff and the standard windows -or linux- onscreen keyboard. Inkscape, Illustrator, Photoshop, 3dsmax, Coreldraw, whatever software I try it works perfect. Occasionally I do simple video and audio editing. *I have a two monitor configuration, sip and puff system is arm mounted on desktop*, I use two reflective dots -to improve efficency- on the right side of my glasses, I can send photoes if you want. I can move the cursor all over the lengh of both monitor, from left to right and vice versa; if the headmouse looses the signal before acclompishing this task, I slighty switch back with my head, Headmouse re-finds dot signal and I finish that cursor movement. **Headmaster** doesn't have this little drawback -very little, You'll not ping pong your cursor all the time-; I felt uncomfortable wearing **HMaster** headset, it's also wired to the PC so you are not free to go away with your wheelchair. A simple dot on a comfortable support is the easyest option. Maybe in the future a lightweight wireless ultrasonic device will give a reborn to **HMaster**. Every InfraRed based device -*SmartNav, Tracker, Headmouse*- suffers from direct sunlight, but your display watching experience does it too, so You will ever not be in direct sunlight.

Today I also tried **QUHA ZONO** gyroscopic device, I was very attracted by this device: wireless and indipendent, enough lightweight, easily portable, can be used outdoor with smartphones etc.. I had to say that I couldnt try it in the best conditions and that I was looking for something performing like my headmouse. And in fact **ZONO** is something else. I need an easily portable -not to be used outdoor- and I'll go with an **Headmouse Nano**. I'll give another try to **ZONO**, but his gyroscoopic ancestor boost tracer seemed to suffer of the same 'kinda floating cursor' behaviour.

When I tried **TrackerPro** it was a bit slower than HMouse, it gave me back a light delay between my head movement and the cursor one. **SmartNav** is much slower so it gives a bigger delay.